# issue with reading result from POST in fetch request to Github API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, github-api

I am using the fetch api to get an access token returned from the github api.

When I check the network tab I see that the token is returned but I am unable to access it in my `fetch` request.

My code looks like this:

```
fetch(`https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=***&client_secret=***&code=${code}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&state=react`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res); // I have already tried return res.json() here
  })
```

The console displays the following error if I return `res.json()`:

> index.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

The [GitHub docs](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/#response) states the response takes the following format:

> By default, the response takes the following form:
>
> `access_token=e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a&token_type=bearer`

I guess it isn't returning valid json but just a string so I am not sure how to access this response.

The response looks like this:

[image]

However, when I try and log out the response I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: Can you check if `res` is a valid JSON?

Comment: Just going to leave this here to save you a lot of time : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: I have been using the console. If you read the question I have shown the error in the console

Comment: Also you have 2x then, but I only see 1 promise.. Yes you are seeing error in console, but you are not debugging.. Breakpoint ?

Comment: @31piy I don't think it is valid son but I am not sure how to get the response - updated question with ref to GitHub docs

Comment: why you are using two then method...after returning you are doing console.log

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `mode: 'no-cors`, browser will restrict to access body. Browser has security for cross domain. If you want to access body you have to call without `mode: 'no-cors` property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

#### This will work

```
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
})
```

#### This will not work

```
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: I need to use `mode: no-cors` to allow the request

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `no-cors`. If github restricting you by cross domain, you have to remove `no-cors` and create your own backend api which get data from github.

Comment: I am getting the response returned, but I am unable to access it in the fetch request

Comment: Yes, browser will take response but will not give acces to JavaScript as security policy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. You've mentioned [this link](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/#response) to the docs. If you read further, you can see that to get response in JSON, you need to include a header named `Accept` with the value of `application/json`.

```
fetch(` ... `, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    })
  }).then(function(res) {
    ...
  })
```

This way, you can apply `.json()` on `res`.